# Hex string as input to scanf in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, scanf, buffer-overflow

Can we give input string by it's hex value in gdb. For example, a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[20];
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Debugging it:

```
ravi@ravi-desktop:~$ gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from /home/ravi/a.out...done.
(gdb) list 1
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   int main() {
4       char buffer[20];
5       fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer);
6       printf("%s", buffer);
7   }
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ravi/a.out 
\x41\x41\x41\x41
\x41\x41\x41\x41
Program exited with code 014.
(gdb) quit
```

I want to input four `A`'s as input using hex value `\x41` but it's considering each character separately.

**The real requirement is I'm playing with Shellcode in Stack-based Buffer Overflow, and I need to input shellcode in hex at a time of debugging.**

Can anybody help me here.

Thank you
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

you can simply read from a socket instead of stdin, which makes it quite easy to set breakpoints in gdb and look what is happening in detail in one shell and inject code in another shell!

that is just an example how you could inject hex into a socket:

```
echo -e "`perl -e 'print "\x14\xee\xff\xbf"x10 . "\x90"x10'`" | nc 127.0.0.1 1337
```

--> printing memory addresses and NOPs with perl and pipe it into nc to localhost(or a remote system) on port 1337 in this case.

That is solving your problem i assume!
if you need assistance to communicate via socket i am sure you will find answers on stackoverflow as well!

Comment: This works for when you use nc to connect to a program remotely.
Thanks @roegi

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting gdb to have this functionality, that it should interpret C-style escapes in the input so that the debugged program gets an `'A'` when you type `\x41`.

Unfortunately that's just not how it works; gdb doesn't sit between the debugged program and the terminal. And terminals don't support that functionality, so it just won't work.